# How to set builtin class methods with python type function?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, python-typing, typing

The following code works as expected

```
class Foo: pass
a1 = Foo
a2 = Foo
print(a1 == a2)
# True
```

now if I dynamically generate them and compare it it doesn't work

```
def eq(a,b):
  return str(a) == str(b)

t1 = type("Foo", (), {"__eq__": eq})
t2 = type("Foo", (), {"__eq__": eq})

print(t1 == t2)
# False
```

Moreover when running this, I get the error

```
print(t1.__eq__(t2))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(t1.__eq__(t2))
TypeError: eq() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

What's the correct way to setup a builtin methods with using a type function ?

sidenote:
I need this kind of functionality, where I am dynamically creating the types either from types(in this case it's a identity function where I return output same as input) or type annotation which are not of type type but either typing.Alias or typing.Generic. Here is the snippet to get bigger picture

```
from typing import List
class Foo: pass

def build_type(type_):
  '''Build type definition of new user-defined types or annotations.'''

  if isinstance(type_, type):
    return type_
  else:
    origin = type_.__origin__ if hasattr(type_, "__origin__") else None
    args = type_.__args__ if hasattr(type_, "__args__") else None
    type_name = str(type_)
    attrs = {
      "__origin__": origin,
      "__args__": args,
      "__hash__": hash((type_name, origin, args))
    }
    return type(type_name, (), attrs)

t1 = build_type(Foo)
t2 = build_type(Foo)
print(t1 == t2) # True

a1 = build_type(List[Foo])
a2 = build_type(List[Foo])

print(a1 == a2) # False
```

Comment: You can't use the `__eq__` method like that with the types, because it is an *instance* method. The types compare differently with `==` because they are separate objects, and there is no rule to make them equal - the default `object` comparison is used. In the first example, `a1` and `a2` are separate names for the same object - the `Foo` class itself.

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? Did you mean to test `a1() == a2()`?

Comment: "What's the correct way to setup a builtin methods with using a type function ?" It's not clear what you want. Are you trying to set up code that allows Python to detect that the `a1` and  `a2` types are "the same" despite being separate instances of `type`? Are you trying to create an `__eq__` instance method for each type, that automatically does the right thing? (What **is** the right thing?) Something else?

Comment: Is there any way to make t1 and t2 same like a1 and a2 ?

Comment: Are you trying to set up code that allows Python to detect that the a1 and a2 types are "the same" despite being separate instances of type?
Yes

Comment: @jtbandes `a1() == a2()` No I need `a1 == a2`, need same types and not same instace

Comment: In that case I would recommend you keep a cache of previously-created types so you can simply avoid creating new ones that have the same methods.

Comment: yes @jtbandes that's the last resort, but I want to make it stateless if possible!

Comment: The types you're building don't make any sense as types. Why are you doing this in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were told in comments, methods have to be members of the class, not of the instance.

As you are dynamically building classes and not simple objects, you should use a custom meta-class with a specific `__eq__` method:

You example would become:

```
...
class Builder(type):
"""Custom meta-class defining type equality as name equality"""
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str(self) == str(other)

def build_type(type_):
  '''Build type definition of new user-defined types or annotations.'''

  if isinstance(type_, type):
    return type_
  else:
    origin = type_.__origin__ if hasattr(type_, "__origin__") else None
    args = type_.__args__ if hasattr(type_, "__args__") else None
    type_name = str(type_)
    attrs = {
      "__origin__": origin,
      "__args__": args,
      "__hash__": hash((type_name, origin, args))
    }
    return Builder(type_name, (), attrs)
...
```

If you run it, you should get as expected:

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

your code currently returns:

```
id(a1)
140415204390672

id(a2)
140415204390672

# a1 and a2 have same object IDs

id(t1)
140415116432032

id(t2)
140415116465120

# t1 and t2 have different object ID
```

but I guess you want to compare:

```
a1.__name__ == a2.__name__
True
```

where `a1.__name__` is `'Foo'`